# block only parts of a domain with fritzbox filterlist

Tags: fritzbox

How can I block only certain parts of a domain with the filterlists of fritzbox?
I know I can block whole domains and subdomains like `abc.com` or `a.abc.com` but I would like to block urls that start with `abc.com/edf/` and didn't get it to work.
I already tried adding `abc.com/edf`, `abc.com/edf/` and `abc.com/edf/*` but even after clearing caches the whole site, and in particular `abc.com/edf/`, would still be accessible.
Am I missing something or is this just not possible with those filterlists?

I have a Fritzbox 7560 with the newest firmware.

Comment: Not possible. This information is encrypted with HTTPS and only your browser can do the job.